# Cocos2dX specific Libraries cannot be resolved after creating Android Project from existing cocos2dx project file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have configured the setup for cocos2dx by using Eclipse, android and windows. 
The following link is the resource I follow to configure.

- http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-setup-cocos2d-x-windows-and-android/#comment-77433

But, after I have done everything that tutorial and creating the Android Project from existing Cocos2dx codes (`HelloCpp`, `HelloLua` and `HelloJavaScript`), I have got the error that Eclipse can not resolve the Cocos2dx specific classes such as `Cocos2dxActivity`.

My Question is do I have to import Cocos2dx Libraries (Jar) files into the Eclipse ? or Did I do something wrong in the set up process ?

Comment: I just got it right .. it is because I ticked the "copy the project into workspace" .. It seems the project only work in the cocos2dx directory (C:\Android\cocos2d-x\samples\HelloCpp\proj.android) .. not in other workspace directory .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You use 2.0.* version of cocos2d-x? Something has changed in that release.

Make sure that you have linked source which point to cocos2dx/platform/android/java/src_common

Check **Project Properties->Java Build Path->Source** dialog

Comment: Thanks @moadib
I have checked that .. Yes,, I have added the Path you mentioned in the Project properties .. but, the application only work when I don't copy the project into my own workspace .. I would like to copy the project into my own workspace .. If I don't copy the project, the changes i made in the project will affect the original templates ??